# Invoking non static class member function of dynamically loaded library

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, shared-libraries

I am writing an app with optional runtime dependency with KWallet. It means if there is KWallet installed on user system it's used and if not it still works but without KWallet support.

Here is how I load the library, it's a static property of my wrapper class. Then in the constructor under condition of state I resolve symbols from the library.

```
QLibrary Core::PSE::KWallet::lib("KF5Wallet");
...
lib.load();  
openWallet = (OpenWallet) lib.resolve("_ZN7KWallet6Wallet10openWalletERK7QStringyNS0_8OpenTypeE");
networkWallet = (NetworkWallet) lib.resolve("_ZN7KWallet6Wallet13NetworkWalletEv");
destructor = (Destructor) lib.resolve("_ZN7KWallet6WalletD2Ev");
```

The same as the QLibrary - function are also static members of my class, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.
Here are definitions from my class

```
typedef ::KWallet::Wallet* (*OpenWallet)(const QString &, WId, ::KWallet::Wallet::OpenType);
typedef QString (*NetworkWallet)();
typedef void (*WalletOpened)(bool);
typedef void (*Destructor)();

static OpenWallet openWallet;
static NetworkWallet networkWallet;
static Destructor destructor;
```

Here is how I allocate an object

```
wallet = openWallet(networkWallet(), 0, ::KWallet::Wallet::Asynchronous);
```

Everything goes fine until the point I need to execute non static members and, especially, destructor. As far as I know, it is supposed to look like that

```
((*wallet).(destructor))()
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I'm totally new to this topic and I have no idea even if I had started in a right way.

So, how do I invoke the destructor of this way loaded class? How do I invoke the rest of it's members? Or shall I better do it in some completely other way?

P.S. I'm aware, there is a DBUS API for KWallet, even some wrapper libraries like qtkeychain, but I want to understand the way of making this kind of dependencies using this example.

Comment: Apart from anything else, why are you attempting to call the destructor explicitly?  Shouldn't you simply use `delete wallet`?

Comment: Honestly - I don't know. Theoretically I should allocate and dealocate the memory in the same module. Even more - my main module have no idea about the code written in virtual destructor of KF5Wallet.so, so, I'm just following my senses and guesses. Do you think this situation is handled somewhere deep and It's gonna be fine for me just to call it like `delete wallet` or even `wallet.deleteLater()`?

Comment: I guess you have write one small .cpp just trying to load the the library and use it. This whole question sufferes from uncomplete code and vague description (although runtime loading of code is hard and Qt is a mess, so its only natural). Also write it in a way that we dont have to know a bit about KWallet except for what is in the question. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The idea is to write a small shared library with wrapper functions like that

```
extern "C" KWallet::Wallet* openWallet(const QString &name, WId w, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType ot = KWallet::Wallet::Synchronous) {
    return KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(name, w, ot);
}
extern "C" void deleteWallet(KWallet::Wallet* w) {
    w->deleteLater();
}
extern "C" const char* networkWallet() {
    return KWallet::Wallet::NetworkWallet().toStdString().c_str();
}
extern "C" int readPassword(KWallet::Wallet* w, const QString &key, QString &value) {
    return w->readPassword(key, value);
}
```

Let's call this little wrapper `foo.so`. So, then you build this `foo.so` and target link at build time to the real dependency, `KWallet` in my case.

Then in the main code you're going to try dynamically load this `foo.so`, not the `KWallet` itself. And if the `KWallet` is absent on the launching machine this `foo.so` is simply not going to load, **that's the trick I had to know!**

Then of course you simply resolve symbols like this

```
QLibrary Core::PSE::KWallet::lib("foo");
...
lib.load();  
openWallet = (OpenWallet) lib.resolve("openWallet");
networkWallet = (NetworkWallet) lib.resolve("networkWallet");
deleteWallet = (DeleteWallet) lib.resolve("deleteWallet");
readPassword = (ReadPassword) lib.resolve("readPassword");
```

And call it like this

```
wallet = openWallet(networkWallet(), 0, ::KWallet::Wallet::Asynchronous);
...
QString password;
int result = readPassword(wallet, *i, password);
...
deleteWallet(wallet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before going into solution I should state that this is very bad idea and I can't see a sensible reason to go this way except if you are using a class from a compiled shared library which you can't edit its source and the class has no alternative virtual interface .

The better way to do this in c++ is to use virtual methods by making a base class containing the functionality you need to use and any subclass in a shared library can override those virtual methods to customize the behaviour .

Now this is the solution to your case :

A non static method of a class has a calling convention of `thiscall` which means that they are like ordinary functions except they take a pointer to the class instance as the first argument , this is the `this` pointer ! In fact methods in c++ (non virtual) are syntactic sugar for c functions which operate on a struct

This snippet of code illustrates :

```
struct somestruct
{
    int j;
};

void add(somestruct* this, int i)
{
    this->j += i;
}


class someclass
{
public:
    void add(int i)
    {
        j += i;
    }
private:
    int j;
};
```

So in your case : for each method declaration add a pointer to the class instance that is the first argument and when you want to call this method on an instance just pass it as the first pointer.

Virtual functions are implemented in two ways :

1 - a vtable inside the class itself like c vtables

2 - a pointer to vtable inside the class so you only have one vtable per class declaration and it's said that this method is better for cache hence it's used by most compilers

Comment: I see, but this is exactly what I'm trying to do! I'm trying to access a third party compiled code having just .h and may be .so which is going to be discovered at the runtime. The idea is to make an optional dependency like here (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/ark/) you see? You just install some other package and have rar support, or 7z support, but it still works without them

Comment: I provided a solution for this case in my answer